# Play video from StreamingAssets folder in Windows Media Player?(Unity 3D)

Tags: unity, windows, video

I can play video which is there in my StreamingAssets folder. But is there a way in which I click a button and the same video gets played in the Windows Media Player. I researched a lot on this but could not find any solution.

This is the code for playing video normally,

```
   using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class VideoDemo : MonoBehaviour
{

public string filePath;
public string result;

void Start() {
    filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Demo.mp4");
    result = "";

}

void OnGUI() {
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10,100,30),"Click Me"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Example());
    }
}

IEnumerator Example ()
{
    if (filePath.Contains ("://")) {
        WWW www = new WWW (filePath);
        yield return www;
        result = www.text;

    } else
    {
        result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText (filePath);

    }
}

  }
```

Kindly share some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply let windows open the default program for a file, this should do:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"file path");
```

If you want more control over what program opens and what arguments are passed, you can use this:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\... path to windows media player";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + file_name + "\"";
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out.One more thing,considering the paths to WMP to be different for different users,how do I go about this?

Comment: It should be somewhere in the registry. This question comes close but is not exactly what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181676/detect-the-installed-version-of-windows-media-player-using-c-sharp

Comment: I will look into it. Anyways, thanks for your time.